# Openvpn instability after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: networking, vpn, 17.04, openvpn

I have a setup that'd been working for many months, using openvpn from the shell to connect to somebody else's server.

After upgrading my machine to Ubuntu 17.04 the openvpn connection constantly fails with soft reset after some minutes. Since I'm using dynamic passwords generated by an external device, the openvpn process is unable to restart the connection, which is very time consuming.

Any ideas on this?

I'm currently using openvpn 2.4.0 on ubuntu 17.04.

TIA

Fernando

Comment: The same configuration is working stable in an Ubuntu 13.10 client.

Comment: Please share some more information, like: 1) If you control the server too, what is the version of the server running? 2) Please share as much as you can from your configuration. 3) Please share as much as you can from the output. There should be a reason why the client resets the connection. This can be a ping-timeout or TLS issues for example. Usually it means a misconfiguration or a configuration that's not explicit enough for both ends with a different version. OpenVPN warns you during connection for any settings different on client compared to server.

Comment: Wild guess: 2.4 introduces a new default for renegotiation limits. `Limit --reneg-bytes to 64MB when using small block ciphers` So perhaps your configuration is insecure and OpenVPN 2.4 adjusts for it by renegotiating every 64 megabyte transferred. Should show up in logs... so please share.

Comment: I have no control over the server and I don't know what version it's running, unfortunately. Here is what seems relevant of my config:

setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
client
server-poll-timeout 4
nobind
remote vpnserver.notreal.com 1194 udp
(...)
dev tun
dev-type tun
ns-cert-type server
reneg-sec 604800
sndbuf 100000
rcvbuf 100000
auth-user-pass login.conf
comp-lzo no
verb 5
log-append /tmp/vpn.log
setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO

key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>

Comment: Your second comment seems to be on target. There is indeed a warning saying "WARNING: cipher with small block size in use, reducing reneg-bytes to 64MB to mitigate SWEET32 attacks.". Does this provoke the soft reset? If so, does he need the password again to renegociate? If so, I'm blocked, since the password expires every minute or so...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include such relevant information. This is not a discussion forum ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenVPN server you are connecting to is running an insecure configuration (using small block ciphers for encrypting packets in the data channel) as indicated in the logs:

```
WARNING: cipher with small block size in use, reducing reneg-bytes to 64MB to mitigate SWEET32 attacks.
```

The 2.4 release of OpenVPN tries to minimize the security impact by renegoniating more often. However, that's a work around and for that reason producing warning messages. As a side effect of renegotiation, you'll have to reauthenticate.

As you said you are not in control of that OpenVPN server, please negotiate with the operator of that OpenVPN server to configure it more securely. It's perfectly possible to be compatible with your 2.4 client without an upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4.

Shamelessly linking to my own blog post (for 2.3 server at the time of writing). After that you will need a new client configuration from him adapted to the new settings. https://blog.g3rt.nl/openvpn-security-tips.html